# Textview background color got changed after adding custom theme to android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview, custom-theme

My app interface originally looked like this. "my name" is a TextView and "my button" is a button which has an image as the background. Minimum sdk is 16.

[image: pic 1]

I changed the action bar color of the app by adding a custom theme. I used the code below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/com_facebook_blue</item>
</style>
```

Then my output came like this.
[image]

All the background color got changed to the new color of the app. I only need to change the color of the action bar.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using minimum sdk as 16. This requires minimum sdk 21

Comment: the theme take from support v7 , so you can use this
And i am also use minimum sdk 16 (P.S. Sorry for my English. I am only learning.)